# Passing elipsis argument to be evaluated within function call within Reduce

Tags: r, function, functional-programming, namespaces, ellipsis

## Background

I have a fun function that compares vectors within a list using `all.equal`. As I'm making use of the `all.equal` I would like to pass relevant `all.equal` arguments via ellipsis. Without the need to pass anything to `all.equal` the function works as desired.

### Function goals

- The function aims to provide modified version of `all.equal` call working on any number of vectors
- Each of the vectors can have any number of elements; however, if all vectors are not of equal lengths the function will return false.
- The function should be able to take advantage of arguments available in `all.equal`. For instance vectors `c(1.1, 2)`, `c(1, 2)`  and `c(1.3, 2)` will be considered equal if `tolerance` argument with the right value is provided. *The question is concerned with getting this to work.*

#### Example

Comparing 1,000 vectors, each consisting of three integers.

```
    compare_multiple_vectors(x = lapply(
              X = vector(mode = "list", length = 1e3),
              FUN = function(...) {
                  c(1, 2, 3)
              }
          ))

    # [1] TRUE
```

## Problem / desired results

`all.equal` called with `tolerance = 1` on the following list of vectors will return expected `TRUE`

```
all.equal(c(1,2), c(1,1), tolerance = 1)
# [1] TRUE
```

The **`tolerance = 1`** argument fails to filter down to inside `Reduce`.

```
compare_multiple_vectors(x = list(c(1,2), c(1,1)), tolerance = 1)
# [1] FALSE
```

The *desired result* should be **`TRUE`**.

---

## Code

```
#' @title Compare Values of Multiple Vectors
#'
#' @description The function compares values across multiple vectors using
#'   \code{\link[base]{all.equal}}.
#'
#' @param x Alist of vectors to compare
#' @param ... as in  \code{\link[base]{all.equal}}
#'
#' @return A logical
#'
#' @export
#'
#' @importFrom checkmate assert_atomic_vector
#'
#' @examples
#' # Returns TRUE
#' compare_multiple_vectors(c(1,1,1), c(1,1,1))
#' # Returns FALSE
#' compare_multiple_vectors(c(1,1,1), c(1,1,1), c(1,2,1))
#' # Returns FALSE
#' compare_multiple_vectors(c(1,2,3), c(3,2,1))
compare_multiple_vectors <- function(x, ...) {
    # Check if all elements of x are atomic vectors
    Vectorize(FUN = checkmate::assert_atomic_vector,
              vectorize.args = "x")(x)

    # Compare list elements
    Reduce(
        f = function(a, b, ...) {
            if (isTRUE(all.equal(target = a, current = b, ...))) {
                a
            } else {
                FALSE
            }
        },
        x = x
    ) -> res_red

    # Return results
    if (isFALSE(res_red)) {
        return(FALSE)
    } else {
        return(TRUE)
    }
}
```

---

## Notes

- I'm interested in making use of ellipsis and leaving the initial call the way it is with

  ```
  compare_multiple_vectors(x = list_of_vectors_to_compare, 
                           ... # all.equal arguments
                           )
  ```

Comment: `Reduce` doesn't have a `...` argument, but `Map` does. Would something like this `Map(function(a, b, ...) all.equal(a, b, ...), list(c(1,2)),  list(c(1,1)), tolerance = 1)` do it? Note that the list is now two lists.

Comment: Or simply `Map(all.equal, list(c(1,2)),  list(c(1,1)), tolerance = 1)`. Apparently, `Map` recognizes the ellipses argument of `all.equal`.

Comment: @RuiBarradas I reckon this could work; how this affects performance as Reduce will always compare two vectors? Also, I want to pass one argument as a list of vectors to check, for Map, this would have to broken down into separate list, what with list that has odd number of vectors?

Comment: I think it's unclear what sorts of comparisons you are attempting and what sort of error checking would be needed. Can we assume that all entries in the list will be of length 2? Or is it the case that some are of different lengths? This all cries out for a set of test cases for testing and a correspond set of explanations why the specified results should be as offered. And wouldn't the results need to be in the form of a list, rather than as a vector? (Voting to close as unclear, but would encourage you to clarify so I can reverse my vote.)

Comment: @42- thanks for looking at this. I’ve clarified what the function is supposed to do.

Comment: The lack of well thought out range of examples persists, despite the call for same. What would be the correct answer for:  `compare_multiple_vectors ( c(1.3, 2), c(1.5, 2) ,  c(2.4, 2), tolerance=1)`. The accepted answer gives `TRUE`, but I think that would not have been what I would have imagined to be correct.

Comment: @42- it would be equivalent to running all.equal on first two vectors, if T. returning first vector and comparing with the last one using all.equal, all of that with tolerance = 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think just need a little change:

```
compare_multiple_vectors <- function(x, ...) {
    # Check if all elements of x are atomic vectors
    Vectorize(FUN = checkmate::assert_atomic_vector,
              vectorize.args = "x")(x)

    # Compare list elements
    Reduce(
        f = function(a, b) {  # <===================== Remove *...*

            if (isTRUE(all.equal(target = a, current = b, ...))) {
                a
            } else {
                FALSE
            }
        },
        x = x
    ) -> res_red

    # Return results
    if (isFALSE(res_red)) {
        return(FALSE)
    } else {
        return(TRUE)
    }
}
```

The arguments *f* of *Reduce* seems to have a **signature** like *function(x, y)*. So *Reduce* will ignore *...* in *f*. If remove the ellipsis of *f*, *...* will reference from the outer space, and will have the right result you want.

Comment: Both you and the OP have failed to demonstrate testing on a range of examples. What about: `compare_multiple_vectors (c(2.4, 2) , c(1,2) , c(-.1, 2) ,tolerance=1)`?

Comment: @42- Try `compare_multiple_vectors (x=list(c(2.4, 2) , c(1,2) , c(-.1, 2)) ,tolerance=1)` ?

Comment: Yes. Why should 2.4 be "equal" to -.1 even with a tolerance of 1.

Comment: @42- Well, my result is *FALSE* , mean *not equal*

Comment: And that is what I get when I repeat it. `compare_multiple_vectors (x=list(c(2.4, 2) , c(1,2) , c(.1, 2)) ,tolerance=1)` does return TRUE but then so does all.eqaul over that "span". I guess it's really the behavior of all.equal that doesn't seem to fit its help page description for tolerances this big.If you make a small edit to you answer, I will be able to reverse my doiwnvote.

Comment: @42-  Sorry, I'm not sure what edit you want. I review the code and I found that we can't compare **across** multiple vectors. These compare should have only **one** target (The first one in *compare_multiple_vectors*).  For target *x* and current *y*,  ```abs(x-y)/x``` is used to compare with *tolerance*. Do you mean the function should not compare across vectors, and should change a name?

Comment: I didn't want any particular edit but comments do not remove the lock on a person's ability to change their vote, so any edit you make, however trivial, should allow me to change my vote.

Comment: @42- Thanks for your patience, I'm newbie here and I get the rule and I edit my answer.